# are asp.net Mvc cms suit to my needs?

Tags: content-management-system

I want to build a web site that
1. use localization
2. will be open only for logged in users
3. according to the user load data form dB

does free cms like umbraco suit to my needs?
which cms is recommended? 
which stated kit I should download?

Thanks,
Ditza

Answer (score 0):

I've done all those things and more with UmbracoCms. I'm not sure of your background in .Net/Mvc but if youre familiar with the concepts you can get a basic site together pretty quickly. Create a DocumentType/Template , along with an Umbraco Controller/Action and Render out some basic text. Then move to Macros for navigation menus and you're on your way. Umbraco has context helpers for getting membership info etc which you can use as keys for your external data lookups etc. If you've build sites in .Net before you could have something up and running in a few hours.